# Hierarchical Angularjs directives not retrieving scope variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm building an AngularJS application.  I use three directives to build the menu.  The titles are inside a i18n file, so most of the attributes are angularjs expressions.  Here is a snippet of how the directives are structured:

```
<navbar title="{{ LABELS.HOME }}" inverse="true">
  <mainmenu>
    <menu-item name="system" title="{{ LABELS.SYSTEM }}">
      <submenu name="users" title="{{ LABELS.USERS }}"></submenu>
    </menu-item>
  </mainmenu>
</navbar>
```

The problem resides on the directive's code.  In the `controller` function (and even on the `link` function), I try to retrieve the `title` and `name` attributes, but they always come up as `undefined` values, even though I do a `console.dir($scope)` I can see the properties,

You can checkout a snippet of the code [here](http://pastebin.com/vT8RjhLz)

Comment: Most people are not going to click on a link to pastebin.com.  You should include your directive code in your question.  I'll guess you're using an isolate scope with the `@` notation in the scope definition.  You need to use attrs.$observe() to see the interpolated values of your attributes in your link function.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild stab here, since you haven't provided any code, but are these being used within an `ng-repeat`?

If so, then the issue is that the linking function is actually called **before** the values are applied to the scope.  This is because `ng-repeat` only bothers performing the link once for the entire loop, then duplicates the nodes afterward, each with the correct `$scope` applied.

The reason you can see the values in the console is that the scope object gets updated after the linking function runs, but ***before*** the console renders it's output.

This leads to a situation where you have something like this:

```
$scope == {};
link();
    console.log($scope); // stores reference to be rendered
$scope.foo = 'bar';
renderConsoleOutput();
```

If you can't fix it using standard binding (for example, `$parent.LABELS.SYSTEM` or something similar), you can wrap your object access in a method, and bind the method instead:

```
// in menu-item directive:
$scope.getLabels = function() { return $scope.LABELS; }
```

```html
// in menu-item template:
<menu-item title="{{ getLabels().SYSTEM }}">
```